# Automatically generate a table with certain content in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a varying number of tables in documents I create with the following structure:

```
+-----------------+--------------+
| Heading R1C1    | Heading R1C2 |
| Paragraph R1C1  |              |
+-----------------+--------------+
| Paragraph R2C1                 |
+--------------------------------+
```

Now I want a automatically generated table at the beginning of the document with the following structure and content:

```
+--------------+-----------------+
| Heading R1C2 | Heading R1C1    |
|              | Paragraph R2C1  |
+--------------+-----------------+
```

How can I accomplish this? It would be ok for me if the heading is moved into an extra row if this makes things easier. I'm using Word 2013.

Comment: I think you need to consider a VBA approach to this. Attempting to do it using field codes or content controls (for example) will probably require a substantial amount of manual intervention and be quite error-prone. But just to clarify, your generated table would include one row for *each of the other tables* ?

Comment: `But just to clarify, your generated table would include one row for each of the other tables ?` That's correct. But before I'd start coding VBA I'd chose another solution where I have easier control over my layout like HTML/CSS.

Comment: How about you put the data for all these tables in a table outside your document (e.g. in an Excel sheet), then use either LINK fields or some such to populate the individual tables and a DATABASE field to generate the "summary" table?